# Can I install a GFCI outlet next to my fuse panel, and run the circuit i need from it?

Tags: electrical

I have a 100 amp fuse panel, and I want to install some GFCI protection to some areas of my home. I was wondering if anyone has tried installing GFCI outlets next to the fuse panel, in a proper box of course, and continuing from them to the circuits they want to protect, just as if they were installing one for the basement circuit?

Comment: Is it actually fuses or is it circuit breakers?

Comment: When I have encountered references to fuses or fuse panels I thought they actually meant breakers? Are there any fuse panels in place in the US anymore?

Comment: @JimStewart -- yes, fused panelboards are still in service in old buildings (like my house)

Comment: @JimStewart Yeah, especially along the east coast of the US, where homes (and thus their wiring) tend to be older.

Comment: Yes, it is a fuse panel.

Comment: Don't forget to use the sticker that says, "GFCI Protected" so that some future individual might have a guess at troubleshooting a dead outlet.

Answer (score 2):

### There's nothing *inherently wrong* with this plan

The NEC just says that GFCI protection is required for such-and-such circuits.  It doesn't specify whether a receptacle, breaker, or deadfront device is used for that job; in your case, since you are dealing with a fused panelboard (aka fuse box), you can't use GFCI breakers, so you need to use a receptacle or deadfront device instead, wired as a feed-through.  Deadfront GFCIs may be preferable to receptacles in this application (to avoid a profusion of receptacles of confusing provenance near your fusebox).

### But, it doesn't scale as well to that *other* interrupter device

However, the situation changes slightly when you start considering *AFCI* protection.  Receptacle-type AFCIs are available; however, they fall into a different class of devices than their breaker-type brethren.  In particular, receptacle-type AFCIs are universally Outlet Branch Circuit (OBC) AFCIs.  These are limited in their protection capabilities compared to breaker-type Branch/Feeder or Combination AFCIs; however, Code allows them to be used as the sole arc-fault protection means in retrofit situations, or if the "home run" to the first outlet is in a metal-clad wiring means (such as metal conduit or armored cable).

Also, receptacle-type devices are available that combine a GFCI with an Outlet Branch Circuit AFCI.  These may be worth considering in your retrofit situation, as AFCI protection is required on most dwelling unit circuits under current NEC rules.

Comment: Thank you for the info on the AFCI's. I had thought about that, but had not tried to figure that part out yet, as I wanted to make sure the idea I had was doable. Really appreciate the help!